# How to conditionally add a Composable based on its size?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Let's say I have some parent Composable such as a BoxWithConstraints and I know the size in dp of this Box. Then lets say I have a child Composable which I would like to only display/(add to the layout) if the child Composable's size would fit within the size of the parent composable.

How could I achieve this? Basically my two questions are, how can I measure the child without displaying it, and then use that measured size to conditionally add the child to the layout.

```
@Composable
fun PseudoView() {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        Modifier.size(width = 200.dp, height = 100.dp)
    ) {
        val childSizeIfLaidOut = somehowGetTheSizeWithoutShowingTheChild()
        val (childWidth, childHeight) = childSizeIfLaidOut 
        if (childWidth <= 200.dp && childHeight <= 100.dp) {
            Child()
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying something along the lines of first trying to add the Child using a Modifier which included .onSizeChanged, and .drawWithContent{} in order to measure the child first and then use those for the conditional like.

```
@Composable
fun PseudoView() {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        Modifier.size(width = 200.dp, height = 100.dp)
    ) {
        var childSize = placeholder
        Child(modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .onSizeChanged { childSize = it }
            .drawWithContent {} // Only use this child for measuring 
        )
        val (childWidth, childHeight) = childSize 
        if (childWidth <= 200.dp && childHeight <= 100.dp) { // Wrong results for boolean.
            Child()
        }
    }
}
```

However I don't get the expected sizes to evaluate the right result in the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after playing around a bit deeper with compose, I found the following solution that solves my particular issue. The idea was to just create a custom layout which conditionally adds the child if it fits in the layout.

```
@Composable
fun ConditionalLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val placeables = mutableListOf<Placeable>()
        for (measurable in measurables) {
            val myConstraints = // Create Constraints based on your requirements.
            val placeable = measurable.measure(myConstraints)
            if (placeable.width <= constraints.maxWidth && placeable.height <= constraints.maxHeight) {
                placeables.add(placeable)
            }
        }
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                // Place placeables.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much there, you just have to convert dp value to pixels or vice versa, since `onSizeChanged` gives you pixels and you want to specify the max size in dp. Also, you don't have to call the composable twice - you can create it invisible at first and then show it once you know it fits:

```
var childSize by remember { mutableStateOf<IntSize?>(null) }
val density = LocalDensity.current

Child(
  modifier = Modifier
    .onSizeChanged { childSize = it }
    .drawWithContent {
      density.run {
        childSize?.let {
          if (it.width <= 200.dp.toPx() && it.height <= 100.dp.toPx()) {
            drawContent()
          }
        }
      }
    }
)
```